# Metabox date month number to word

Tags: metabox, date

I use custom metabox with date (day, month and year). The problem is when I try to transform date number to date word - for example 10 to be October. I use this code:

```
function eventposttype_get_the_month_abbr($month) {
global $wp_locale;
for ( $i = 1; $i < 13; $i = $i +1 ) {
            if ( $i == $month )
                $monthabbr = $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev( $wp_locale->get_month( $i ) );
            }
return $monthabbr;
}
```

But now the month is displayed only with three symbols - Oct. I like to be full month name. Is there any way to define it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wherever you're calling your `eventposttype_get_the_month_abbr` function, e.g., `$month_string = eventposttype_get_the_month_abbr($month)`, couldn't you instead use: `$month_string = $wp_locale->get_month($month)` (using @manny's answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are using is specifically for the month abbreviation, (Oct).  You should be using this:

```
function eventposttype_get_the_month($month) {
global $wp_locale;
for ( $i = 1; $i < 13; $i = $i +1 ) {
            if ( $i == $month )
                $month =$wp_locale->get_month( $i ) ;
            }
return $monthabbr;
}
```

Comment: Kool! Didn't even know that the locals object contains such methods. +1

Comment: @kaiser I didn't either.  Google pwns all :p

Comment: Psst! Don't tell! ;)